# Migrate typescript code from VS to Sublime

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, knockout.js, typescript, sublimetext2

VS can build successfully, but sublime failed.
many .ts files have code like this:

```
import BindingEngineFactory = require("KOBindingEngine");
```

while "KOBindingEngine" is not at that route, its route is defined

```
"KOBindingEngine": "BindingEngines/KOBindingEngine"
```

in **requireConfigPaths.js** file.

```
if (typeof require === 'function' && typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object') {
    module.exports = requireConfigPaths;
}
```

I think the reason VS can build successfully is due to the code below

```
<Content Include="Scripts\Home\Configuration\requireConfigPaths.js" />
```

I don't know how to add this in sublime. so I got the error msg:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'KOBindingEngine'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details about exactly **how** you are attempting to build the Typescript, including which (if any) plugin you are using, what the build system file looks like, and the contents of any settings files for the plugin. Finally, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code you are trying to compile.